# Proving continuity of a distance function measured between a point on a line and a continuous surface

Tags: real-analysis

Let a point P belongs to a line L i.e. P∈L,

Let a surface S is defined by a continuous function S(x, y, z) such that line L does not intersect with S. Assume, S is at least C0 continuous.

If distance function D is defined by distance of any point P on line to S i.e. D = distance(P, S), would it be a continuous function ∀P? How can we prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For metric spaces $X = (X,d)$ and any subsets $S ⊆ X$, the distance to $S$ defined as
$$d_S \colon X → [0..∞),~x ↦ \inf\, \{d(s,x);~s ∈ S\}$$
is always continuous. To see this, let $ε > 0$ and choose $δ = ε/2$ (but any $δ < ε$ would do). For any $x, y ∈ X$ with $d(x,y) < δ$ and any $s ∈ S$, you have

\begin{align*}
d(x,s) &≤ d(x,y) + d(y,s) < δ + d(y,s)\\
d(y,s) &≤ d(y,x) + d(x,s) < δ + d(x,s).\\
\end{align*}

Isolating the terms containing $s$ and then taking infima over $S$, we get $\pm (d_S(x) - d_S(y)) ≤ δ <ε$.

This proves that $d_S$ is uniformly continuous.